# How add value on xml in specified node

Tags: c#, xml

I need write program on c#, which check, if exist node on xml. If not: insert value. So I have tree path: **./a/d** and some line, which I need insert:

```
<e name="aaa" value="bbb" />
```

How read and insert value in correct place? This is original xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <a>
      <b>
      <c></c>
      </b>
    </a>
```

After , I need XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <a>
      <b>
      <c></c>
      </b>
      <d>
        <e name="aaa" value="bbb" />
      </d>
    </a>
```

So, can you help me with code?

Comment: Did you try something already? Did you read about the `XDocument` class? If you haven't, I invite you to do so and then present your findings so that we could discuss. At the current stage this looks more like a description of a problem you would handle to a software developer you have just hired rather than a software developer asking for help from his peers on a public forum.

Comment: Side note - you 'inserted' value in wrong place - it's `a/d` instead of `a/b/d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy with `LINQ to XML`

```
var xDoc = XElement.Load("path");
var elemens = xDoc.Elements("a").First().Element("b");
element.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("d", 
                           new XElement("e", new XAttribute("name","aaa"),
                                             new XAttribute("value","bbb"))));
xDoc.Save("path");
```

Also you should take a look at documentation:

1. [Adding Elements, Attributes, and Nodes to an XML Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [XNode.AddAfterSelf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.addafterself%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)